# Why is Base Class Method Called When Derived Class Method Should be Called

Tags: c++

The code below calls the base class `eval` when IMO it should be calling the `NotGate` version. It works correctly in the `R3` invocation but not the `R4` invocation.

Added at time numerous `typeid` calls to identify the actual 'gates' and find for some reason the type of the gate in `NotGate` is changed during the initialization to storage as a variable to the abstract gate when `operator!` is called. It doesn't happen with `operator*`, or other similar operators in my complete code.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
struct LGAbs {
    enum NodeState {
        Failure, Success, Running
    };
    LGAbs() {
    }
    virtual ~LGAbs() {
    }

    virtual NodeState eval();
};
//---------------------------------------------------------------------
LGAbs::NodeState LGAbs::eval() {
    return LGAbs::Failure;
}
//----------------------------------------------------------------------
struct TrueGate : public LGAbs {
    TrueGate() {
    }

    virtual LGAbs::NodeState eval() override {
        return Success;
    }
};
//----------------------------------------------------------------------
struct NotGate : public LGAbs {
    NotGate(LGAbs& g) :
        mG { g } {
    }
    virtual LGAbs::NodeState eval() override {
        cerr << typeid( mG).name() << endl;
        return mG.eval();
    }
    LGAbs& mG;
};
//----------------------------------------------------------------------
struct AndGate : public LGAbs {
    AndGate(LGAbs& g1, LGAbs& g2) :
        mG1 { g1 }, mG2 { g2 } {
    }
    virtual LGAbs::NodeState eval() override {
        return ((mG1.eval() == LGAbs::Success) && (mG2.eval() == LGAbs::Success)) ? LGAbs::Success : LGAbs::Failure;
    }
    LGAbs& mG1;
    LGAbs& mG2;
};
//----------------------------------------------------------------------
template <typename T1, typename T2>
inline AndGate operator *(T1&& lhs, T2&& rhs) {
    AndGate gate { lhs, rhs };
    // ***** Added typeid
    cerr << "op* " << typeid( gate).name() << '\t' << typeid( gate.mG1).name() << endl;
    return gate;
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------
template <typename T1>
inline NotGate operator !(T1&& lhs) {
    NotGate gate(lhs);
    cerr << "op! " << typeid( gate).name() << '\t' << typeid( gate.mG).name() << endl;
    return gate;
}
//----------------------------------------------------------------------
int main() {
    TrueGate t;
    // *** Added r1
    auto r1 { (t * t) };
    cerr << "R1 " << r1.eval() << '\n' << endl;

    auto r2 { !t };
    cerr << "R2 " << r2.eval() << '\n' << endl;

    cerr << "R3 " << ( !(t * t)).eval() << '\n' << endl;

    auto r4 { !(t * t) };
    cerr << "R4 " << r4.eval() << '\n' << endl;

    cerr << "end " << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The output shows how `R3` evaluates properly but `R4` fails calling the base class version.

```
op* 7AndGate    8TrueGate
R1 1

op! 7NotGate    8TrueGate
R2 8TrueGate
1

R3 op! 7NotGate 7AndGate
7AndGate
1

op! 7NotGate    7AndGate
R4 5LGAbs
0

end
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a general principle that you're running afoul of here...  If you have a member variable that is a reference, you are probably doing something wrong. This is not *always* the case. But if you find yourself doing it, alarm bells should be going off in your head.

You are invoking undefined behavior when calling `eval` on `r4`. The expression `(t * t)` creates a temporary `AndGate` and then a reference to that gets stuffed into a temporary `NotGate` when `operator !` is called. Then `r4` is bound to the temporary `NotGate` (thereby extending it's lifetime) then the temporary `AndGate` that the `NotGate` has a reference to is destructed. After that, you call `eval` on the `NotGate` that has had its lifetime extended by being assigned to `r4`. Then it calls `eval` on the destructed `AndGate` and that's when you get undefined behavior.

In this particular case, the undefined behavior results in the base class destructor being called.  But, the nature of undefined behavior is such that absolutely anything can happen there, so there is nothing to be read into what actually did happen.

Though, the reason it happened in this particular way was that the destructor for `AndGate` restored the virtual table pointer for the base class before calling the base class destructor, which did nothing. This is not at all guaranteed behavior. As I said, it's undefined behavior, and so absolutely anything is allowed there. That's just what happened in this particular instance with this particular compiler.

The reason that you are not invoking undefined behavior in the R3 case is that temporaries are guaranteed to last until the end of the expression they're created in. So, since you're not storing a reference to the temporary somewhere, then using it in a later expression, everything is still alive.

There are two ways to save your program from undefined behavior.

The first is to change all the uses of `LGAbs &` in your classes to `::std::unique_ptr<LGAbs>` and use `::std::make_unique<T>` in your operators.

The second is to make all of your classes representing gates into template classes and keeping copies of the items that were passed in. You should then remove the base class and make `eval` not be a virtual function.

Either will work.

One (the template method) will only allow you to construct expressions at compile time and will create a LOT of classes (though most of them will be optimized out of existence). The code it creates will be very efficient. But there will be no way to construct an expression at run time when you don't know all the pieces it's made of.

The other will be a lot slower and do a bunch of memory allocation. But it will allow you to construct expressions at run time, perhaps even by parsing expressions people type into the program.

There are ways to do hybrid approaches too, but then things start getting a little more complex.

Here is example of how you might do this with the `unique_ptr` method. It requires C++14 to work:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <type_traits>

using namespace std;
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
struct LGAbs {
    enum NodeState {
        Failure, Success, Running
    };
    LGAbs() {
    }
    virtual ~LGAbs() {
    }

    virtual NodeState eval();
};
//---------------------------------------------------------------------
LGAbs::NodeState LGAbs::eval() {
    return LGAbs::Failure;
}
//----------------------------------------------------------------------
struct TrueGate : public LGAbs {
    TrueGate() {
    }

    virtual LGAbs::NodeState eval() override {
        return Success;
    }
};
//----------------------------------------------------------------------
struct NotGate : public LGAbs {
    NotGate(::std::unique_ptr<LGAbs> g) :
         mG { ::std::move(g) } {
    }
    virtual LGAbs::NodeState eval() override {
        cerr << typeid( mG).name() << endl;
        return (mG->eval() == Success) ? Failure : Success;
    }
    ::std::unique_ptr<LGAbs> mG;
};
//----------------------------------------------------------------------
struct AndGate : public LGAbs {
    AndGate(::std::unique_ptr<LGAbs> g1, ::std::unique_ptr<LGAbs> g2) :
         mG1 { ::std::move(g1) }, mG2 { ::std::move(g2) } {
    }
    virtual LGAbs::NodeState eval() override {
        return (mG1->eval() == Success) && (mG2->eval() == Success) ?
            Success : Failure;
    }
    ::std::unique_ptr<LGAbs> mG1;
    ::std::unique_ptr<LGAbs> mG2;
};
//----------------------------------------------------------------------
template <typename T1, typename T2>
inline AndGate operator *(T1 &&lhs, T2 &&rhs) {
    using NRT1 = typename ::std::remove_reference<T1>::type;
    using NRT2 = typename ::std::remove_reference<T2>::type;
    AndGate gate { ::std::make_unique<NRT1>(::std::move(lhs)), ::std::make_unique<NRT2>(::std::move(rhs)) };
    return gate;
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------
template <typename T1>
inline NotGate operator !(T1 &&lhs) {
    using NRT1 = typename ::std::remove_reference<T1>::type;
    NotGate gate{ ::std::make_unique<NRT1>(::std::move(lhs)) };
    cerr << "op! " << typeid( gate).name() << '\t' << typeid( *gate.mG).name() << endl;
    return gate;
}
//----------------------------------------------------------------------
int main() {
    TrueGate t;

    auto r2 { !t };
    cerr << "R2 " << r2.eval() << "\n\n";

    cerr << "R3 " << ( !(t * t)).eval() << "\n\n";

    auto r4 { !(t * t) };
    cerr << "R4 " << r4.eval() << "\n\n";

    cerr << "end \n";

    return 0;
}
```

And here is a version that uses templates (and works with C++11). Notice how neither version has any member variables that are references:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

enum class NodeState {
   Failure, Success, Running
};

template <class T>
struct is_gate_class {
   static const bool value = ::std::is_same<decltype(reinterpret_cast<T const *>(0)->eval()), NodeState>::value;
};

template <class T>
class NotGate {
 public:
   explicit constexpr NotGate(T const &v) : v_(v) { }

   constexpr NodeState eval() const {
      return v_.eval() == NodeState::Success ?
         NodeState::Failure : NodeState::Success;
   }

 private:
   T v_;
};

template <class T1, class T2>
class AndGate {
 public:
   explicit constexpr AndGate(T1 const &v1, T2 const &v2) : v1_(v1), v2_(v2) {}

   constexpr NodeState eval() const {
      return (v1_.eval() != NodeState::Failure) &&
         (v2_.eval() != NodeState::Failure) ?
         NodeState::Success : NodeState::Failure;
   }

 private:
   T1 v1_;
   T2 v2_;
};

class TrueGate {
 public:
   constexpr NodeState eval() const {
      return NodeState::Success;
   }
};

template <class T>
constexpr typename ::std::enable_if<is_gate_class<T>::value, NotGate<T>>::type
operator !(T const &v)
{
   return NotGate<T>(v);
}

template <class T1, class T2>
constexpr typename ::std::enable_if<is_gate_class<T1>::value &&
                                    is_gate_class<T2>::value,
                                    AndGate<T1, T2>>::type
operator *(T1 const &v1, T2 const &v2)
{
   return AndGate<T1, T2>(v1, v2);
}

::std::ostream &operator <<(::std::ostream &os, NodeState const &ns)
{
   char const *valstr = nullptr;

   switch (ns) {
    case NodeState::Success:
      valstr = "Success";
      break;
    case NodeState::Failure:
      valstr = "Failure";
      break;
    case NodeState::Running:
      valstr = "Running";
      break;
   }
   return os << valstr;
}

int main()
{
   using ::std::cerr;

    TrueGate t;

    auto r1 { t };
    cerr << "R1 " << r1.eval() << "\n\n";

    auto r2 { !t };
    cerr << "R2 " << r2.eval() << "\n\n";

    cerr << "R3 " << ( !(t * t)).eval() << "\n\n";

    auto r4 { !(t * t) };
    cerr << "R4 " << r4.eval() << "\n\n";

    cerr << "end \n";

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your answer is very good and explanatory. Appreciate the code examples. In creating a 'minimal code' example I omitted an R1 case using the AndGate which creates an `auto` variable that is then evaluated the same as the R4 case. It works as do some other similar gates so is something else going on? The only one that doesn't work is the `operator!' which is why I posted this. I added this additional code to the OP. I'll note that I also created a `NOT` function that is the same as the `operator!` and it also fails in the same way so this is not something unique to using `operator!`.

Comment: @rm1948 - Your R1 case only creates one temporary, the `AndGate`. `t` is an actual variable. And then you immediately bind a reference to that temporary (or create a copy of it, it doesn't really matter which) which extends its lifetime to that of the reference. Your R4 case is different because there are two temporaries, the `AndGate`, then the `NotGate` which references it. The only thing who's lifetime extends beyond the expression is the `NotGate`. Also, undefined behavior is allowed to do anything, even work just like you want it to. :-) But, your R1 case does not invoke UB.

Comment: Ran into an issue using the non-template version. The `operator+` for OrGate ( not shown) is considered for std::string concatenation. Expect similar problems with the other `operator` overloads. Don't expect a solution, just mentioning it.

Comment: @rm1948 - Oh, oops. Yeah, it would be. You'll need to use `::std::enable_if` with `::std::is_base_of`. I'll leave how as an exercise to the reader. I can't wait for C++ concepts to become a thing.

Comment: Couldn't get it so posted new question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56502143/cant-restrict-overload-of-template-function-operator-to-my-class-hierarchy-u