# Can't restrict overload of template function `operator+` to my class hierarchy using `enable_if` and `is_base_of`

Tags: c++, templates, operator-overloading

I'm creating an `operator+` using a template function for a type hierarchy. First simple attempt worked fine until I tried to concatenate a string in another part of the code and GCC 8.3 tried to use my `operator+`.

Trying to use `enable_if` and `is_base_of` to restrict my version to my types so SFINAE handles the issue.

One attempt among many is:

```
template <  //
    typename T1, //
    typename T2, typename std::enable_if_t<std::is_base_of_v<LogicGateAbs, T2>, T2>       //
>
inline OrGate operator +(T1&& lhs, T2&& rhs) {
    return OrGate { LogicGateAbs::make_concrete(lhs), LogicGateAbs::make_concrete(rhs) };
}
```

Here the compiler gives the types correctly:

```
./src2/test.cpp:90:11: error: no match for ‘operator+’ (operand types are ‘TrueGate’ and ‘TrueGate’)
     (True + True);
      ~~~~~^~~~~~
```

But why does it then return 'false' for `is_base_of` since `LogicGateAbs` is the base of `TrueGate`?

```
../src2/test.cpp:83:15: note: candidate: ‘template<class T1, class T2, typename std::enable_if<is_base_of_v<LogicGateAbs, T2>, T2>::type <anonymous> > OrGate operator+(T1&&, T2&&)’
 inline OrGate operator +(T1&& lhs, T2&& rhs) {
               ^~~~~~~~
../src2/test.cpp:83:15: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
../src2/test.cpp:81:32: error: no type named ‘type’ in ‘struct std::enable_if<false, TrueGate&>’
     typename T2, typename std::enable_if_t<std::is_base_of_v<LogicGateAbs, T2>, T2>       //
                                ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Gone through every version of this on StackOverflow without getting a version to work.

The base function works as needed. The rvalue reference is necessary for the inputs are often temporary values.

Comment: Your template declaration appears to have a typo. It should be `..., typename=std::enable_if_t<...`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice the `TrueGate&` in the error message: that’s `T2`, deduced as such because the argument is an lvalue.  `std:is_base_of` requires actual class types, so use `std::remove_reference_t`.

Comment: That made the test work. The other was the missing `=` sign that @Sam Varshavchik mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

You need `::std::remove_reference`, yes. But you also need to check the types of both arguments. :-/

```
template <typename T1, typename T2>
inline typename
::std::enable_if<
    ::std::is_base_of_v<LogicGateAbs, typename std::remove_reference_t<T1>> &&
    ::std::is_base_of_v<LogicGateAbs, typename std::remove_reference_t<T2>>,
    AndGate>::type
operator *(T1 &&lhs, T2 &&rhs) {
    using NRT1 = typename ::std::remove_reference<T1>::type;
    using NRT2 = typename ::std::remove_reference<T2>::type;
    AndGate gate { ::std::make_unique<NRT1>(::std::move(lhs)), ::std::make_unique<NRT2>(::std::move(rhs)) };
    return gate;
}
```

Now it won't match if either side of the expression isn't derived from `LogicGateAbs`. I actually have a really bad feeling about the non-template version. These *only* work if the arguments are temporaries. The only reason it's working for `TrueGate` is that the move constructor for it is equivalent to its copy constructor. The move constructors for the things with `unique_ptr` members are destructive moves.

Comment: I was planning on checking both sides once I got it working for one. I am only going to use the template version. I just fell back to the non-template to demonstrate it worked and to get type id data. 

You used a different approach, which I'd attempted at one point, of using the return to test the inputs and generate the return type. 

I tucked the `using NRT` lines into a static method in LogicalGateAbs to make the  code more readable. If you like, pm tweet me at @r_merriam. Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

The final version required `std::remove_reference_t` and the `=` supplied by @Davis and `@Sam. Kudos to both.

In LogicalGateAbs:

```
class LogicalGateAbs {
...
    template <typename T>
    static inline auto make_concrete(T&& rhs) {
        using NRT = typename std::remove_reference<T>::type;
        return std::make_unique < NRT > (std::move(rhs));
    }
};
```

And the version of `operator+`:

```
//----------------------------------------------------------------------
template <typename T>
using check_type = std::enable_if_t<std::is_base_of_v<LogicGateAbs, typename std::remove_reference_t<T>>, T>;
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------
template <typename T1, typename = check_type<T1>, typename T2, typename = check_type<T2> >
inline OrGate operator +(T1&& lhs, T2&& rhs) {
    return OrGate { "op+", LogicGateAbs::make_concrete(lhs), LogicGateAbs::make_concrete(rhs) };
}
```

Comment: It needs more. :-) And there's a slightly better way to do it.

Comment: Do you see advantage in using the type check in the return as you posted vs the template section used here?

Comment: No, not really. I chose the return because I have a distaste for template parameters that are meaningless. :-)